# Handling Multiple Events from a Single Listener

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, event-handling

I want to have a single event listener for multiple events and depending on the
type of event i want to handle them separately.

Something similar to [Swiz framework](http://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Event+Handling#EventHandling-HandlingMultipleEventsfromaSingleMethod) see: 'Handling Multiple Events from a Single Method'

i have a piece of code like

```
     var toolOptions:UIComponent=ToolOptions.createToolOptions(type);
            if (options != null)
            {
                options.addEventListener(Event.SELECT,toolOptionSelectedHandler);
                someViewComponent.addOptions(toolOptions);
            }

   // handle depending on event type
    private function toolOptionSelectedHandler(event:*):void
    {
        //handle depending on type of event fired
        // type cast  event depending on type and  retrieve VO from event 
        //and send handle it..

        //SomeToolObj.handle(event.VO);    

    }
```

In above ***toolOptions*** is a mxml component which get dynamically created based on
'type'.

Also which type of event should be dispatch the event from the component? eg: Event.SELECT

To be more precise the above is basically required for a toolbar.
When user selects a tool,he is shown options for a tool and when he selects options,
tool should apply them to object on the view.

Is there a better way to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what I understand:

You have different tools. Each of the tools has a list of options. You click an option, and a single event handler should perform some action depending on the option.

```
object on the view 1 : n tools 1 : n options
```

---

Create a custom event `OptionEvent.SELECT` with the property `optionType`.

```
public class OptionEvent extends Event {
    public static const SELECT : String = "optionEvent_select";
    public var optionType : String;
    public function OptionEvent(type : String) {
        super(type, true); // bubbles
    }
}
```

When the user selects the option, dispatch the event like this:

```
var event : OptionEvent = new OptionEvent(OptionEvent.SELECT);
event.optionType = "border";
dispatchEvent(event);
```

Listen to the event like you do:

```
var toolOptions:UIComponent=ToolOptions.createToolOptions(type);
if (options != null) {
    options.addEventListener(OptionEvent.SELECT,toolOptionSelectedHandler);
    someViewComponent.addOptions(toolOptions);
}
```

Distinguish the type of option by determining the option type:

```
private function toolOptionSelectedHandler(event : OptionEvent) : void {
     var optionType = event.optionType;
     switch (optionType) {
         case "border":
             addBorderToView();             
             break;
         case "rotation":
             rotateView();             
             break;
     }
}
```

**UPDATE** - How to set up a list of option values in OptionEvent:

```
public class OptionEvent extends Event {
    public static const SELECT : String = "optionEvent_select";
    public var optionType : String;
    private var _optionValues : Object;

    public function OptionEvent(type : String) {
        _optionValues = new Object();
        super(type, true); // bubbles
    }

    public function setOptionValue(property : String, value : *) : void {
        _optionValues[property] = value;
    }

    public function getOptionValue(property : String) : * {
        return _optionValues[property];
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for answer..yes i came up with something very similar.. Should options be part of the event too? i have different options for different tools.

Comment: Since your `OptionEvent` bubbles, you can easily retrieve the actual option within `toolOptionSelectedHandler`: `var option : MyOption = event.target`.

Comment: is it ok to put options inside the event itself? since my version of optionEvent is non-bubbling.. declared one more field 'options'(keyvalue pair) inside the event .. Can each tool-options have their own typed VO??

Comment: I don't actually know how your selection process is constructed. Apparently its from importance to get the list of all (or at least all selected) options of a single tool. I guess you have different options to adjust and then a single submit button for each tool. Now you want to know what option values are submitted. There are different ways to transmit these values. 1 - Let the tool (`event.currentTarget`) return the list of current option values. 2 - Set the values right to the event. The second thing I will put in my answer.

Comment: thx again :)  yes i used the above now..                           options = {"key1":value1,...,"keyn":valuen}

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to try something like this:
http://blog.iconara.net/2008/03/30/separating-event-handling-from-event-filtering/

and I've done a solution I'm a bit more comfortable with by using a Chain of Responsibility with links that have separate determineResponsibility and meetResponsibility methods, where the specific event data is stored when the link is created.  If we find a match between that and the event that gets passed into the chain, then we call meetResponsibility.  Otherwise, we call the next link in the chain.

For more on COR, check out http://www.as3dp.com/2008/01/14/actionscript-30-chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern-decoupling-request-and-request-handler/